# iPhone friendly websites with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: iphone, iphone-web-app

Are there any resources or guidance out there on how to make iPhone friendly web applications?

In my case specifically, I'd like to use ASP.NET MVC, but since that all runs on the server, I know it'll boil down to just markup/css/javascript considerations.

*edit:* as I find other resources not mentioned here, I will update the question text :-)

- [CSS-Tricks ScreenCast on Designing for the iPhone](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/38-basics-tips-on-designing-for-the-iphone/)

Comment: did anyone else die of boredom watching that css-tricks video? I couldn't make it past the 2 minute explanation of the existence of browser detection functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There’s an [iPhone article on Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/iphone-development-12-tips/) (which usefully shows you how to target stylesheets at just the iPhone, whilst hiding them from Internet Explorer—Apple's documentation doesn't).
- Craig Hockenberry wrote [Put Your Content In My Pocket](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/putyourcontentinmypocket) at A List Apart.
- A Flickr developer posted some lessons learned: http://code.flickr.com/blog/2008/10/27/lessons-learned-while-building-an-iphone-site/
- +1 for Apple’s documentation as mentioned by Boot To The Head—horses’ mouth and all that: they have pretty comprehensive stuff on neat CSS properties that are only really supported by Safari, like [CSS animations](http://webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/) and [CSS Transitions](http://ejohn.org/blog/css-animations-and-javascript/).

Answer (score 3):

Scot Hanselman had a great presentation at Mix 09. Click here [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixMobileWebSitesWithASPNETMVCAndTheMobileBrowserDefinitionFile.aspx).

Also look at the Mobile Device Browser File=>[LINK](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/). It is open source at codeplex.

"What is the Mobile Device Browser Definition File?

The Mobile Device Browser Definition File contains capability definitions for individual mobile devices and browsers. At run time, ASP.NET uses this .browser file, along with the information in the HTTP request header, to determine what type of device/browser has made the request and what the capabilities of that device are. This information is exposed to the developer through the Request.Browser property and allows them to tailor the presentation of their web page to suit the capabilities of the target device." - Codeplex

Answer (score 1):

The definitive resource is Apple's [Safari Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/safari/mobile.php).

Comment: Broken link, not very helpful.